# How to use a for loop through unknown value

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, for-loop

I have this array shown below. Within my JavaScriptI need to console out all the customer numbers, but some of the objects the existing employees do not have a customer and therefore it is not consoling out all of the employees. Help!

I have tried doing if(!tickets[k].customernumber){console.log{"undefined")} but it still does not seem to work.

```
for (var k = 0; k < tickets.length; k++) {
    console.log(tickets[k].name)

[ { id: 506652,
    name: 'Sara Johns',
    age: '26',
    occupation: 'architect',
    status: 'new',
    customernumber: 26222234 },
{ id: 502452,
    name: 'Emily Johnson',
    age: '22',
    occupation: 'architect',
    status: 'existing' },
{ id: 326652,
    name: 'Claire Stevens',
    age: '23',
    occupation: 'junior architect',
    status: 'new',
    customernumber: 26222234 }
```

Comment: Recheck your brackets. Missing closing bracket in for loop.

Comment: You said _"need to console out all the customer numbers"_ and then _"it is not consoling out all of the employees"_. Im confused. Do you want to print all employees even if they dont have a customer number ?

Comment: Im not sure if you observed this. `if(!tickets[k].customernumber){console.log{"undefined")}` has to be `if(!tickets[k].customernumber){console.log("undefined")}`. The object needs to be closed with `]` and loop with `}`. Probably just formatting errors.

Comment: Hi Mad Piranha, yes sorry that is just a formatting error.

Comment: and yes, I am trying to console out all of the employees even if they dont have a customer number..but I need the for loop through tickets in order to access the ticket information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will print all `customernumber`s, skipping the records that do not have one:

```
tickets.filter(function(item) {
    return item.customernumber;
}).forEach(function(item) {
    console.log(item.customernumber);
});
```

Note that duplicate ids are currently not filtered out.

You can check MDN for more info on [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).

Comment: You could use `.map()` instead of `.forEach` and then do even more cascading if needed (like `.sort()`).

Comment: It is also a wee bit faster, and less typing.  :^)

Answer (score 0):

```js
var tickets = [{
  id: 506652,
  name: 'Sara Johns',
  age: '26',
  occupation: 'architect',
  status: 'new',
  customernumber: 26222234
}, {
  id: 502452,
  name: 'Emily Johnson',
  age: '22',
  occupation: 'architect',
  status: 'existing'
}, {
  id: 326652,
  name: 'Claire Stevens',
  age: '23',
  occupation: 'junior architect',
  status: 'new',
  customernumber: 26222234
}]
for (var k = 0; k < tickets.length; k++) {
  console.log(tickets[k].customernumber ? tickets[k].customernumber : 'undefined')
}
```

Comment: Please provide context behind your answer.